# R: Exporting .eps to Word with UTF-8 fonts

Tags: r, utf-8, fonts

I'm having trouble exporting images with Lithuanian fonts (UTF-8) from R to MS Word. What I've found so far by researching ways to do it, is the following example:

```
postscript("foo.eps", horizontal = FALSE, onefile = FALSE, 
            paper = "special", height = 7, width = 7,
            colormodel = 'rgb')
plot(density(rnorm(100)), main = "ąčęėįšųūž")
dev.off()
```

The image is imported successfully to word, however I'm having troubles with the fonts. Inside R it looks fine, however the final output
looks like this: [image: looks like this]. It seems there is a problem with the fonts. I've tried embedding them using the following code:

```
library(extrafont)
## Only for the first run: Made sure the ghostScript was reachable:
Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "C:/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.19/bin/gswin32c.exe")

embed_fonts('foo.eps', outfile='foof.eps')
```

However, the final result was .eps file, which did not get imported into MS Word with message "This image cannot currently be displayed".

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

NB: It is not necessary that the format of the image be in EPS format, but I haven't found any other format that Word does understand, which is also close to PDF in its quality (JPEG/PNG quality is too low).

EDIT: including both of the .eps files to a LaTeX file resulted in two correct images, so the problem might be in the way the Word interprets and loads the file.. Any ideas where?

Comment: Read `?postscriptFonts` and `?dev.interactive`

Comment: You can save it as a pdf, if you like (`cairo_pdf` handles accents nicely, it seems), and then insert the pdf into Word as an image. Alternatively, you can use `knitr` and just knit directly to Word, which handles accents nicely, and lets you set dpi in the chunk options if it's not sharp enough.